# Problema conectar enviar datos a mi BASE DE DATOS : SERVIDOR MARIADB

Tags: php, mariadb

Esta enviando datos desde mi login a mi  servidor de base de dato pero no , me salen los registro que serian  usuario y  password , me podrían ayudar con esto ?

```
  <?php
    require 'db.php';
    $message = '';
    if (!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO login (usuario, password) VALUES (:usuario, :password)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $_POST['usuario']);
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $message = 'Successfully created new user';
        } else {
            $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
        }
    }
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    
    <head>
        <title>Registro</title>
    
        <!--JQUERY-->
        <!-- librerias-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- FRAMEWORK BOOTSTRAP para el estilo de la pagina-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Los iconos tipo Solid de Fontawesome-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
    
        <!-- css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/index.css">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Registro</h1>
        <div class="modal-dialog text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-8 main-section">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="col-12 user-img">
                        <img src="static/img/login2.png" />
                    </div>
    
                    <?php if (!empty($message)) : ?>
                        <p> <?= $message ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <form action="registro.php" class="col-12" method="get">
                        <div class="form-group" id="user-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" name="usuario" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="contrasena-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contrasena" name="password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ingresar" name="Ingresar"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Ingresar </button>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

---

Este seria  la conexión de la base de datos , que podria estar mal ?

```
 <?php
    $server = 'localhost:3307';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'inicio';
    
    try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      die('Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
```

Bueno ya intentado todo , pero nada solo deseo una sugerencia o algún error en mi codigo que se podría mejorar
Esto seria un proyecto estoy haciendo , y esto es lo único que me falta , para terminar , y no resuelvo el problema de enviar datos a mi servidor mariadb

Comment: @BetaM **entonces seria post en formulario?**

Comment: @BetaM lo logre gracias bro